# lightning event to show record type selection screen during record creation

Tags: lightning-aura-components

is there any lightning event to show record type selection during record creation.force:create record doesnt have this capability.please provide your inputs.I tried a lot but couldnt find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot mark as duplicate as the answer is not accepted or upvoted I am copying the answer from *Carlos Iribar* here:

[Record Type selection in $A.get("e.force:createRecord") in lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159029/record-type-selection-in-a-gete-forcecreaterecord-in-lightning)

Currently, it's not possible select a record type in the createRecord component. 
You can create a dropdown or something with the record types options and then call the createRecord component passing the record type.

Example

```
var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Contact",
        "recordTypeId": ""
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
```

This a dropdown example for select the record type

```
<div class="source-center-slds" >
        <div class="slds-p-around--x-large">
            <ui:inputSelect class="slds-select_container myselector"  label="{!'Select ' + v.label +  ' Record Type: '}" aura:id="levels">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.types}" var="item">
                    <ui:inputSelectOption class="slds-select" text="{!item.Id}" label="{!item.Name}"/>      
                </aura:iteration>
            </ui:inputSelect>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected slds-m-top--medium" onclick="{!c.create}">New</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

v.types is an array with the record types values