# I want to set record type while creating record in lightning component through e.force:createRecord. But I am not able to do so

Tags: lightning-aura-components, record-type, create-records, force

I want to set record type while creating record in lightning component through e.force:createRecord. But I am not able to do so.
I tried using custom label and even I tried hardcoding still It is not showing correct record type and it is showing default record type for record creation.
Please find below code for javascript controller:

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
        console.log(recId);

        var action = component.get("c.getdetails");
        action.setParams({
            "sId": recId
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
                console.log("Success" + JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
                component.set("v.sampleRequest", response.getReturnValue());
                var sampProd = component.get("v.sampleRequest");

                 if(sampProd.Lead__c === sampProd.Contact__c){
                    var Name = sampProd.Contact__r.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                   var Name = sampProd.Lead__r.Name; 
                }



                var createSampleProduct = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
                var staticRecordLabel = $A.get("$Label.c.UsCanSampleProductRecordType");
                createSampleProduct.setParams({
                    "entityApiName": "Sample_Product__c",
                    "RecordTypeId": '0121b0000004aeSAAQ',
                    "defaultFieldValues": {
                        'Sample_Request__c' : component.get("v.recordId"),
                        'Name__c': Name,                    
                    }
                });
                createSampleProduct.fire();
            } else {
                console.log("Fail");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

I tried hardcoding:

```
var staticRecordLabel = $A.get("$Label.c.UsCanSampleProductRecordType");
            createSampleProduct.setParams({
                "entityApiName": "Sample_Product__c",
                "RecordTypeId": '0121b0000004aeSAAQ',
```

I have tried using:

```
**var staticRecordLabel = $A.get("$Label.c.UsCanSampleProductRecordType");**
            createSampleProduct.setParams({
                "entityApiName": "Sample_Product__c",
                "RecordTypeId": staticRecordLabel ,
```

It is taking me to record creation page with default record type and not with record type that I want to set.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159029/record-type-selection-in-a-gete-forcecreaterecord-in-lightning

Comment: Can you remove the comma after 'Name__c': Name and run the code? Do the record type has been added to your profile? While fetching the values from label, are you considering the api name of label?

Comment: Issue was due to case sensitive nature of lightning only.It got resolved when I used recordTypeId instead of RecordTypeId

Comment: @Sharmila please add that as an answer so that the question can be considered resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was due to case sensitive nature of lightning only.It got resolved when I used recordTypeId instead of RecordTypeId